# How can ergodicity explain thermalization

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ergodicity

I am reading up on thermalization in classical systems. As most systems are ergodic, mostly through the mechanism of dynamical chaos, they will explore their whole allowed phasespace and we can replace time averages with ensemble averages over all allowed microstates. This is what statistical mechanics is based on.

But this exploration of the phasespace is also exponential in time, before the system has explored a huge part of its phasespace a lot of time has passed. We also don't take time averages to infinity, but expect a system to thermalize and the observables to take on a steady value with small fluctuations in a finite time. So how can we explain systems that thermalize and take on values that we expect in thermal equilibrium in times that do not exponentially diverge, as we observe in the real world. What am I missing in my explanation here?

Anyone got any good links about this?

Comment: This issue is already addressed in other questions on this site. In fact, ergodicity, as usually stated, is neither sufficient (because it does not address the issue you raise of the necessarily finite time averages), nor necessary (since it requires equality of the time and ensemble averages for all observables) for the justification of the microcanonical ensemble. This is discussed in detail in [Gallavotti's book](https://ipparco.roma1.infn.it/pagine/deposito/1998/libro.pdf), see for instance Section 1.7.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had indeed already found similar questions on here but had not found any satisfying or complete answers yet. Thanks for the extra reading material, it is much appreciated.

Comment: There is an extensive literature on this topic, see for instance [this paper](http://phil.elte.hu/~redei/cikkek/ergos.pdf) and references therein. There are certainly more recent ones, of course.

Comment: And this beautiful  and very readable [paper by Bricmont](https://arxiv.org/pdf/chao-dyn/9603009.pdf) (see Section 4.2 in particular, for this topic)

Comment: And, to finish, let me point out that there are *many* nonergodic systems. In fact, this is probably the case for most systems of interest in statistical mechanics. The KAM theorem is particularly relevant here.

Comment: I know about the KAM theorem, but these remaining perturbed quasi-stable orbits vanish when more degrees of freedom are added, so in the thermodynamic limit this only applies very weakly anymore. But thanks for the many references! Cannot thank you enough.

Comment: I have read most of the works now right now. Most of them explain why statistical mechanics works and I agree to it, and I understand there are definitely problems with just stating that it flows from the system being ergodic. But this was about the equilibrium state itself mostly, now specifically to my question of thermalization, from e.g. a highly non equilibrium state. I have read nowhere how a system quickly relaxes to an equilibrum state then. How do you see how this flows from the dynamics then?

Comment: Oh, by and large, it is still an open problem (at least for a mathematician). There have been remarkable results in this direction for the Boltzmann equation, but (1) they are still very far from what you'd like, (2) they only apply in very specific limits. For general Hamiltonian dynamics? It's still widely open. From the point of view of physicists, the situation may be very different (but then they'll make all the assumptions they require, with no serious justification, so it really depends what you consider to be an answer to the question...).

Comment: On a heuristic level, let me just say this: with respect to the microcanonical measure, most of phase space corresponds to equilibrium microstates: all macroscopic observables will be almost surely constant. So, provided that your initial conditions are not "pathological", it is not very surprising that the values you observe when making macroscopic measurements quickly converge to what they should: it's the value they get on almost all of the phase space (w.r.t. the microcanonical measure). Of course, this is all very much circular reasoning.

Comment: About what I said in the last comment, there is this old but very nice [paper by Lanford](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0112756). Of course, much more is known today (application of large deviations theory to statistical mechanics).

Comment: (As you might not have access to a library right now, with the current situation, let me give you a [link](https://b-ok.org/book/455387/44a1d6) to where you can illegally download Lanford's paper. Once the situation improves, somebody can delete the link if they think it's better.)

Comment: @Yvan_Velenik please write out your answer in a single full-scale text below, it is worth remembering beyond as a bunch of comments! Thanks.

Comment: @hyportnex : Thanks, but these were just supposed to be suggestions, not an answer, even put all together. I don't consider myself enough of an expert on these issues (in particular, from the point of view of physicists).